# PHP - Object Array Intersect and Merge keeping object intact

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

I have an multidimensional array containing an array of objects returned from a DB:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [image_id] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [image_id] => 5
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [image_id] => 6
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [image_id] => 7
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [image_id] => 5
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [image_id] => 6
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [image_id] => 5
                )
        )
)
```

I need to be able to intersect the nested arrays to only keep the image_id's that are present in all array sets. So in the example above this would only return the image_id = 5.

I need to keep this as an object array which looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [image_id] => 5
        )
)
```

I have tried some code from other posts. This is similar [php - array intersect and merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449983/php-array-intersect-and-merge) however they are trying to remove duplicates which is slightly different case.

All cases I have seen comparing arrays are where the arrays are known (i.e. $arr1, $arr2). the user case for this could be a multi array of any length.

Any help would be appreciated as have been round in circles trying to find a solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try writing the required code yourself rather than trying to find code someone else has written

Comment: what a version of php do you use?

Comment: I am running 5.5 locally - this will sit on a new server which will likely have a more up-to-date version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first we need to loop through the image_ids and get the ones that duplicate. Then we need to rebuild the required structure.

```
<?php

$test_array = [
    [
        (object)['image_id' => 1],
        (object)['image_id' => 2],
        (object)['image_id' => 3],
        (object)['image_id' => 4],
        (object)['image_id' => 5],
    ],
    [
        (object)['image_id' => 2],
        (object)['image_id' => 3],
    ],
    [
        (object)['image_id' => 1],
        (object)['image_id' => 2],
        (object)['image_id' => 3],
    ]
];


$first_iteration = true;
$duplicates = [];

foreach ($test_array as $outer_key => $outer_array) {

    $current_array_values = [];
    foreach ($outer_array as $image_id) {
        $current_array_values[] = $image_id->image_id;
    }

    // If first iteration, then we will have
    // no IDs to check against.
    if ($first_iteration) {
        $duplicates = $current_array_values;
        $first_iteration = false;
    } else {
        $duplicates = array_intersect($duplicates, $current_array_values);
    }   
}

$output = [];
foreach($duplicates as $duplicate) {
    $output[] = (object)['image_id' => $duplicate];
}
```

$output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#11 (1) {
    ["image_id"]=>
    int(2)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#12 (1) {
    ["image_id"]=>
    int(3)
  }
}
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: Thank you...am going to try this now and see how I get on

Comment: All tested and working perfectly. Thank you for your help mkveksas

Comment: @swood my pleasure!